# How do I combine two attributes using uniq?

Tags: ruby

Currently I am doing the following and was wondering if there was a way of merging this?

```
merged = list_with_objects_that_have_url_and_name_attributes
merged = merged.uniq{|ex| ex.url }
merged = merged.uniq{|ex| ex.name }
```

I'd like something like:

```
merged.uniq{|ex| ex.name || ex.url}
```

Comment: give us some sample inputs, and outputs.only code is not sufficient.. Does merger is array or Hash?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to use `uniq` where elements that compare equal are semantically different nevertheless

Comment: @RubyLovely hashes don't have a `uniq` method, it's an array.

Comment: For example, your code maps the array `[{url:1, name:3}, {url:2, name:3}, {url:1, name:4}]` to `[{url:1, name:3}]`, but it maps `[{url:1, name:4}, {url:2, name:3}, {url:1, name:3}]` (same array, different order) to `[{url:1, name:4}, {url:2, name:3}]` (assuming the behavior of `uniq` as mandated by the example in the documentation, but not by the documentation itself)

Comment: If equal URL implies equal name, this can, in fact, be simplified. Very easily. Even without using the `uniq!` method.

Comment: @RubyLovely `h` is not a hash. It's a one-element array with a single hash inside (curly braces are implied, equal keys overwrite each other)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite what you asked for, but it's compact:

```
merged.uniq!(&:url).uniq!(&:name)
```

Comment: You are assuming `merged` is not referenced from elsewhere. Should be mentioned.

Comment: @JanDvorak The OP assigns to `merged`. I think we're on safe territory.

Comment: Maybe the intended side-effect was to clone the array. Perhaps not, but the difference in semantics should be mentioned nevertheless IMO.

Comment: Also, you're assuming `merged` _is_ an array ;-)